# I am getting the error: ld returned 1 exit status while trying to use make

Tags: c, makefile

Im getting this error while trying to run my code using my makefile:

```
find_bits.o: In function `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx':
(.text+0x30): multiple definition of `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.gnu.linkonce.t.__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
find_bits.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
find_bits.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in find_bits.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'open_bits' failed
make: *** [open_bits] Error 1
```

My makefile code:

```
open_bits: find_bits.o
    gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall find_bits.o -o open_bits
find_bits.o: find_bits.c
    gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall find_bits.c -o find_bits.o
```

My actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{/*main*/
    /*Creating the 2 long numbers that will get compared
    also creating the count variable to store the amount of equal activated bits in the numbers
    and another one that will have the decimal value of x&y*/
    unsigned long x,y;
    int count, decimal_outcome;
    count = 0;
    printf("\n Enter 2 numbers in the form of 1, 2: ");/*get the numbers from the user*/
    scanf("%lu,%lu",&x,&y);
    printf("\n You have entered the numbers: %lu, %lu",x,y);
    decimal_outcome = x&y;
    /*The while loop will convert the decimal outcome of x&y to binary
    while checking the open bits and adding to count*/
    while(decimal_outcome!=0){/*while*/
        if(decimal_outcome%2&1)
            count++;
        decimal_outcome = decimal_outcome/2;
    }/*while*/
    printf("\n x and y have %d activated bits in the same spots \n", count);/*printing the amount of equal activated bits*/
    return 0;
}/*main*/
```

I searched for solutions for this problem but nothing seemed to have the exact problem I am having.
I am also very new to coding with C so if my mistake is a one which I shouldn't have got with some common knowledge in the language I am sorry for bothering you with my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To improve quality for future questions a bit, please don't just put the summary of compilation into the title. That message is like "something went wrong". The important information is in the error messages that are printed above the final "ld returned 1" message. These are also the messages you can put into a search engine. A search string like "multiple definition of" will result in way more useful results than "ld returned 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `-c` option to create an object file instead of executable binary.

```
find_bits.o: find_bits.c
    gcc -c -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall find_bits.c -o find_bits.o
```

Comment: Even better is to delete this recipe completely.  Add `-ansi -pedantic -g -Wall` to CFLAGS and let make use the default rules.

Comment: Thanks! the makefile works now, I should probably look more into the subject of makefiles...

Answer (score 1):

This `make` rule ...

> ```
> find_bits.o: find_bits.c
>     gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall find_bits.c -o find_bits.o
> ```

... builds and links a *program* named `find_bits.o`.  Then this rule ...

> ```
> open_bits: find_bits.o
>     gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall find_bits.o -o open_bits
> ```

... asks that program `find_bits.o` be linked as if it were an object file, to form program `open_bits`.

Use the `-c` option to compile to an object file without going on to link the result:

```
CFLAGS = -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall

open_bits: find_bits.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

find_bits.o: find_bits.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```